# Replicate Curl unix-socket command in Java

Tags: java, curl, unix-socket

I want to get the same string standard outputted by curl when I type something like:

```
curl --unix-socket file.sock http://path/to/rest/request
```

In my Java code.
I figured out I need to use AFUNIXSocket, but I can set just the socket file on connection, so I suppose I have to manage my http connection manually.

Is there a way to make it easier? How do I start an http connection through the socket I create?

Comment: Did you go over the AFUNIXSocket source code as found here :
https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket/blob/master/junixsocket-common/src/main/java/org/newsclub/net/unix/AFUNIXSocket.java

I think you might get a good answer there....

Comment: Ive already seen this, but I didnt get any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried to manage the http connection by myself, it works but Im still looking for a cleaner way to do that.
That's how I did:

```
AFUNIXSocket s = AFUNIXSocket.newInstance();
AFUNIXSocketAddress sockAdd = new AFUNIXSocketAddress(new File("file.sock"));

s.connect(sockAdd);

BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());


pw.write("GET /to/rest/request HTTP/1.1\r\n");

pw.write("Host: path\r\n");
pw.write("Accept:*/*\r\n");
pw.write("\r\n");
pw.flush();
String reply = "";

Thread.sleep(500);
while (bf.ready())
   reply = reply + bf.readLine() + "\n";
```

That is the same to do a curl call like that:

```
curl --unix-socket file.sock http://path/to/rest/request
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same puzzle from a Scala (and Akka streams) point of view. At least your answer verifies that one needs to encapsulate the HTTP request headers, but it should would be nice to leverage the higher-level HTTP APIs in Java somehow.